# Pseudo LDAP with SQL-View-Backend

Tags: sql, sql-server, ldap

I need a possibility for "quering a SQL database through LDAP". Our telephones can extend the contact list by binding LDAP directories. We need the contacts of our ERP (SQL Server) in the phone book. Is there a nice way to simulate an only search-able LDAP server which uses an extern database view?

//Jonny

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org) You can write a custom partition that delegates the search
to your preferred backend or you can also write a simple Intereceptor and overwrite the search() method.